# Jquery: Hover on popup window element, read parent position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup

I have **move-able(drag) popup** windows inside a html page like this:[image]

when i hover the .prd_img element inside the popup, i able to get the mouse X Y coordinate like this:

```
$(".prd_img").hover(function(e){
    window.parent.$("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.src +"' alt='product image' /><\/p>");    


 $(this).mousemove(function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;

    console.log("x: "+currentMousePos.x+" y:"+currentMousePos.y);
    window.parent.$("#preview").css({'display':'block', 'top': currentMousePos.y, 'left':currentMousePos.x});
 });    

},
function(){
    window.parent.$("#preview").remove();
});
```

i will display the the large version of image on parent window using: 
 `window.parent.$("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.src +"' alt='product image' /><\/p>");`

**problem is:** the mouse over coordinate is from the popup itself, not from parent (main page). When it show the `<p id='preview'>` on parent, the position will look like below:
[image]
whenever i drag move the popup windows, the image will show at almost the same position.

how do i make it, whenever i drag and drop the popup, when i hover the .prd_img class, i will always read the parent coordinate, instead of popup coordinate, so that the image of enlarged to  at parent, it will always look like this:[image]

the css for #preview is:

```
#preview{
    position: absolute;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background:#333;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    z-index: 9999;
    pointer-events: none;
    }
```

any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried adding the relatieve position of the popup to the parent to your X and Y?

Comment: relative do not work, it go to bottom right of the parent page, and cannot be seen.

Comment: I suggest adding the `#preview` element inside the popup itself instead of appending it to the body ... then you just set its `left` and `top` values to 0 and it will stick to where the popup is moved because its just inside it